# How Cubism.js library works

Tags: javascript

I am very curious of how tooltip in Cubism.js works. http://square.github.io/cubism/
Since i am quite new to javascript, I will appreciate if someone gives me any hint. I am really interested in making tooltip in which data value shows by hovering cursor around the graph.
I have seen the library but could not find anything regarding the tooltip..

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The tooltips showing on the graph itself there are just spans above the canvas showing the graph.
The axis labels at the top is built using svg.